# Accessing raw data from LAZ file in Python with Open Source software?

Tags: python, lidar, open-source-gis, laz

Is there anyway to access raw "**LAZ**" (*not LAS*) datasets in Python? I was trying to with ArcPy (I'd prefer not too), but it doesn't seem able to access LAZ. I'd prefer to work with the raw LAZ file and develop something to give access to other users.

My goal here is to do some filtering of the data to produce different features in  a shapefile format. To do that I need to access the raw points XYZ, classification, and other fields. I've done this before, but never with a LAZ, only LAS.

I am looking for an Open Source, free solution, I know ESRI has some tools, but I am hoping to run this tool without any licensing needed.

This is related to [What LiDAR processing tools are available in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88322/what-lidar-processing-tools-are-available-in-python), but specific to compressed LiDAR format (LAZ) and more about accessing the data than processing it.

Comment: LasPy should do what your looking for: https://pypi.org/project/laspy/  . Not sure on its functionality with LAZ though.

Comment: @OtonabeeGIS I can't seem to get it to work. Having issues with LasZip.

Comment: [You should just need laszip in the system path](https://github.com/laspy/laspy/blob/master/laspy/base.py#L25)

Comment: Have you tried PDAL? https://pdal.io/python.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A convenient way to get point cloud data to Python is to use the 
[PDAL Python](https://pypi.org/project/PDAL/) extension. [PDAL](https://pdal.io) uses the concept of [pipelines](https://pdal.io/pipeline.html) (much 
like a [GDAL VRT](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html) for point clouds instead of rasters) to allow users to orchestrate the processing of point cloud data. With the PDAL Python extension, you can 
read a [LAZ](https://laszip.org) file into a [Numpy array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) and then do whatever you need 
to with it. The easiest way to do all this is with [Conda](https://conda.io/).

Here's what it does

- constructs a new environment with Conda
- installs `pdal`, `python-pdal`, and `matplotlib` modules
- reads a LAZ file over the internet using a PDAL pipeline
- plots a histogram of all of the dimensions of the file into a file called `histogram.png`

Run these commands in your shell environment after installing miniconda to create a new 
environment.

```
    $ conda env remove -n gisse

    $ conda create -n gisse -c conda-forge pdal python-pdal matplotlib -y

    $ conda activate gisse
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

pipeline="""{
  "pipeline": [
    {
        "type": "readers.las",
        "filename": "https://github.com/PDAL/data/blob/master/autzen/stadium-utm.laz?raw=true"
    },
    {
        "type": "filters.sort",
        "dimension": "Z"
    }
  ]
}"""



import pdal
r = pdal.Pipeline(pipeline)
r.validate()
r.execute()
arrays = r.arrays


import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
from io import BytesIO

def make_plot(dimensions, filename, dpi=300):
    figure_position = 1
    row = 1
    fig = plt.figure(figure_position, figsize=(6, 8.5), dpi=dpi)
    keys = dimensions.dtype.fields.keys()

    for key in keys:
        dimension = dimensions[key]
        ax = fig.add_subplot(len(keys), 1, row)

        n, bins, patches = ax.hist( dimension, 30,
                                    normed=0,
                                    facecolor='grey',
                                    alpha=0.75,
                                    align='mid',
                                    histtype='stepfilled',
                                    linewidth=None)

        ax.set_ylabel(key, size=10, rotation='horizontal')
        ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        ax.set_yticklabels('')
        ax.set_yticks((),)
        ax.set_xlim(min(dimension), max(dimension))
        ax.set_ylim(min(n), max(n))
        row = row + 1
        figure_position = figure_position + 1
    output = BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(output,format="PNG")

    o = open(filename, 'wb')
    o.write(output.getvalue())
    o.close()
    return True


make_plot(arrays[0], 'histogram.png')
```

[image: histogram]